# Which class contains meta-data about models in EF core?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I need to do some optimizations of updates/deletes on materialized views so that I can do some bulk operations bypassing EF. I need to know if entity has any related entities. How can I determine that at runtime; which type contains meta-data about the model in EF Core?

Comment: `context.Model`

Comment: EF Core 7 manage bulk operation : [ExecuteUpdate and ExecuteDelete (Bulk updates)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#executeupdate-and-executedelete-bulk-updates)

Comment: Many EF Core extension already do this : [Tools & Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/)